# How to target the current page's nav element and fade out its css "current" class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, fade, nav

I've got a simple nav bar. The link that corresponds to the current page has a simple CSS class called "current" on it, as you'd expect. All the links have a nice hover transition effect with the 'ease-in-out' property lasting 0.3 seconds. Problem is, when the user clicks a different link on the nav bar, he won't see the ease-out effect because the page will switch instantly. I know that I can delay the page switch via jQuery with a setTimeout() function, but I don't quite get how to target the "current" class on the link element and tell the browser to slowly fade out the "current" CSS class before switching to the next page.

Is this making any sense? Current HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="current">About</a></li>
<li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Super simple navigation with the current page having a CSS class hover class, which is defined after the basic link styles as:

```
nav ul li a, nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-size: 2.4em;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 15px;
   -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
   -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active, nav ul li a.current{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 140px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 140px;
    border-radius: 140px;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

I'm using jQuery anyway for something else in the site, so a jQuery answer is perfectly acceptable. I hope I'm being clear enough with my problem. Basically, I don't want an abrupt page switch for the user when he clicks on a different nav link. I want the "current" CSS class to fade out for 0.3 seconds before the browser goes to the new page. I know that I have the same styles applied to the CSS "current" class and the link hover state, I can change that if that's what it takes for the code to work.

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps out.
Any advice/suggestions/tips are appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend against doing this. Don't make your site less responsive than it needs to be just to show an animation. Can't you just make animate on hover?

Comment: @Chris: Yes I could, but this is for a portfolio site and it's kind of artsy; the abrupt page transition seriously breaks the user experience because some other elements on the page remain static while others fade out. I really don't think a 0.3 second delay is going to make it that much less responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fade out a class per se.  You can create a CSS3 transition that is triggered by adding or removing a class and will create the desired animation, fade or whatever.

So, for example, you could have a CSS3 transition set for the `opacity` property.  The `.current` class in your CSS could specify `opacity: 1` and the default CSS condition (when there is no `.current` class) could be for `opacity: 0;`.  Then, when you remove the `current` class from the object, the item will gradually fade to 0 opacity.

Or, you could have a class `fadeOut` that has an `opacity: 0` CSS rule and with a CSS transition for `opacity` set on the object you just add the `fadeOut` class to the object.

As it sounds like you already know, if the link click is going to change the page, then you'd have to delay the processing of the link href with `setTimeout()` in order to be able to see the fade transition and probably prevent the default processing of the link.